# Switch Case c# store Data

Tags: c#, database, switch-statement

I'm storing data from an xml file in a database, but I can't find how to do it the right way.

I'm using a switch case to go through the tags and get my data which works fine, but I want the data to be stored in one row so they have to go simultaneously in the database.

Not every tag has the same data stored. So for example Tag 1 has identity but Tag 2 is null, Tag 3 again has data.

```
string identity= null;
string birth = null;
if (xmlFile.Depth >= 9)
{
    switch (xmlFile.Name)
    {
        case "identity":
            listXML.Add(new SearchedTags() { TagLine = xmlFile.GetAttribute("V") });
            identity = listXML[listXML.Count - 1].TagLine;
            break;
        case "birth"
            listXML.Add(new SearchedTags() { TagLine = xmlFile.GetAttribute("V") });
            birth = listXML[listXML.Count - 1].TagLine;
            break;
    }
```

I don't include the classes here because they are not relevant in my opinion. if I debug birth and identity have values.

```
private static void InsertValues(string a, string b)
{
    using (NpgsqlConnection con = ConnectorDatabase.GetConnection())
    {
        con.Open();

        string sql = @"INSERT INTO public.Database(IDENTITY, BIRth)values('" + a + "','" + b + "')";
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(psql, con);
        int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

So if I use my method after the switch case statement the values are null;

if I use it inside for Example the Birth case it only includes data where the case of birth is true which isn't the case every time so I will miss out on Data.

I tried some things but the best outcome was that in my database every data was there, but not in the same row so identity x had only null values in his row but the column what always have its data. Hope you understand what I mean

EDIT:
I realized now why I can't use it after the switch case. So actually I think I have to do it like that:

```
string identity= null;
string birth = null;
if (xmlFile.Depth >= 9)
{
    switch (xmlFile.Name)
    {
        case "identity":
            listXML.Add(new SearchedTags() { TagLine = xmlFile.GetAttribute("V") });
            identity = listXML[listXML.Count - 1].TagLine;
            break;
        case "birth"
            listXML.Add(new SearchedTags() { TagLine = xmlFile.GetAttribute("V") });
            birth = listXML[listXML.Count - 1].TagLine;
            break;
    }
    InsertValues(identiy, birth);
```

I didn't include all of the code but the xmlFile is an XmlTextReader.
which is in a while loop with while( xmlFile.Read).
Which leads to the Problem, so as I said the Xml File got a lot of Tags, but I only need identity and birth.
if I put it after the switch. it goes through the while loop and the next tag may be "IDNUMBER".
So it doesn't jump in the switch case and I would do the InsertValues() method again. which is wrong. That means I get Double Data which leads to an Primary Key error.

*SOLVED*
For anyone who run in the same Problem I declared a boolean as true.

```
string identity= null;
string birth = null;
bool isRunning= true;
if (xmlFile.Depth >= 9)
{
    switch (xmlFile.Name)
    {
        case "identity":
            listXML.Add(new SearchedTags() { TagLine = xmlFile.GetAttribute("V") });
            identity = listXML[listXML.Count - 1].TagLine;
            isRunning = true;
break;
        case "birth"
            listXML.Add(new SearchedTags() { TagLine = xmlFile.GetAttribute("V") });
            birth = listXML[listXML.Count - 1].TagLine;
            break;
    }
if(isRunning == true)
{
    InsertValues(identiy, birth);
    isRunning = false;
}
```

I know that every Tag has identity in the XML File so I can for sure say every time it goes trough the Tag it will put on true and goes to further code.
It helped me writing the Problem down. Maybe I should do this more often.

XML FILE EXAMPLE

```
<person>
<identity V="Peter"/>
<Birth V="1995"/>
<IDNUMBER V="1021"/>
<JOB V="JANITOR"/>
</person>
```

Problem was as I said that because of the while loop, it goes through every tag, when it hits IDNUMBER and JOB it skipped the switch case, causing problems with my primary Key. Cause the values of "identiy" and "birth" didn't changed.

Comment: Maybe interesting know the format of the XML or a small XML example.

Comment: Please show your full code containing the `while` loop, it's unclear exactly what your issue is.

Comment: Side note: You have a major SQL injection issue, you need to use parameters

Comment: Ah i will keep that in mind for next time, i solved it myself, i dont know what you mean with the SQL injection the code is running fine for me

Comment: `@"INSERT INTO public.Database(IDENTITY, BIRth)values('" + a + "','" + b + "')"` that's SQL injection. It works now, but not for example when someone decides their name is `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--` see https://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

Might be a scope related problem, you could try storing identity and birth in static properties.

Comment: Would have to try it. my guess would have been that i do an if statement before InsertValues(), but i would need the right parameters to succed so something that is true if the switch case is used and false if it got skipped